# Анимация между переходами активити

Tags: android, android-animation, android-app-compat-activity

Как сделать `circular reval animation` при переходе на другое активити?

Уже где мог перерыл, только с `FloatingActionButton` есть, а с обычными кнопками нет(

Comment: Какая разница, какая кнопка - FAB или обычная, алгоритм тот же самый.

Comment: @pavlofff нет, там флот сначала выходит на середину а потом уже анимация

Comment: Код FAB открытый. Возьмите из него эту фичу и создайте кастом обычную кнопку

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличное описание на сайте [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html?hl=ru), даже на русском языке, вроде там все ясно описано. Переход на новое активити можно выполнить с помощью интента:

```
 startActivity(intent,
          ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
```

Не забудьте указать в стиле теме, аттрибут:

> android:windowContentTransitions